# Изменение направления текста Word с использованием Apache Poi/

Tags: java, apache-poi

Необходимо изменить направление текста в таблице в документе созданном с помощью Apache Poi, подскажите каким образом можно это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел следующее решение. Необходимо скачит библиотеку ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar (не ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar, так как нету org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTextDirection)

```
    XWPFTableCell tableCell = table.getRow(r).getCell(c); 
 tableCell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTextDirection().setVal(STTextDirection.BT_LR);
    paragraph = tableCell.getParagraphArray(0);
    run = paragraph.createRun();  
    run.setText("text");
```